# why onClick Event of C# not working in <td> of table tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio, onclick

I'm trying to dynamically generate onClick event in  tag by concatenating strings and im getting the result i want, but when I click on  element then event is not working. I thought that may be  not support onClick event and tried other ways like putting onClick in ,   etc, but nothing works. please help me here.

my html code:

```
<table class="downloadTable">
        <tr>
            <th class="sn">SN</th>
            <th class="assi">Notes Title</th>
            <th class="pby">Subject</th>
            <th class="ld">Posted by</th>
            <th class="dp">Posted date</th>
        </tr><%=getNotesData()%> 
    </table>
```

my C# coding:

```
 public string getAssignmentData()
{
    string data = "";
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["_logdb"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        string query = "Select * from _tbNotes";
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader drd = comm.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (drd.HasRows)
            {
                while (drd.Read())
                {
                    int id = 1;
                    string title = drd.GetString(1);
                    string sub = drd.GetString(2);
                    string auth = drd.GetString(3);
                    data += "<tr OnClick=\"_storeDetails(4)\"><td>" + id + "</td><td>" + title + "</td><td>" + sub + "</td><td>" + auth + "</td></tr>";
                    id++;
                }
            }
        }
        return data;

    }
}
```

Function that im calling onClick()

```
protected void _storeDetails(int uid)
{
    Session["AssignmentNo"] = uid;
    Response.Redirect("~/ViewAssignment.aspx");
}
```

resulting browser code:

```
<table class="massi tb">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th class="sn">SN</th>
        <th class="assi">Assignment Title</th>
        <th class="pby">Posted By</th>
        <th class="pd">Post Date</th>
        <th class="ld">Last Submit Date</th>
    </tr>


    <tr onclick="_storeDetails(4)">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Java assignment 1</td>
        <td>java</td>
        <td>tanvi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr onclick="_storeDetails(4)">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>vector graphics</td>
        <td>web development</td>
        <td>pandey</td>
    </tr>
    <tr onclick="_storeDetails(4)">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Advance java assignment 2</td>
        <td>Advance Java</td>
        <td>Tenvi Gautam</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td onclick="_storeDetails">Java assignment 1</td>
        <td>java</td>
        <td>tanvi</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

please help me what im doing wrong here. also if any alternative you doing this same work then tell me.

Answer (score 2):

That will not work because this:

```
<tr onclick="_storeDetails(4)">
```

means to call the funtion `_storeDetails` on the client side. Therefore, the function must be a javascript function.

Your `storeDetails` is a method on the server side. You need to do it like this instead:

```
<tr onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('_storeDetails','4');">
```

Then in the server side, you need this code:

```
if (this.IsPostBack)
{
    if (Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == "_storeDetails")
    {
        // This can fail if you pass a value which is not an integer
        // You can use TryParse instead if you want.
        int param = int.Parse(Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]);
        _storeDetails(param);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call a server-side function from client-side code, which in your example is not going to work. You have a few options:

- Do a postback and set the desired control as the source. You need to create a client javascript function:

  `<tr onclick="_storeDetails(4)">`

  ```
      <script type="text/javascript">
      function _storeDetails(parameter)
      {
        __doPostBack('_storeDetailsClick', parameter)
      }
      </script>
  ```

  You could then handle postback in Page_Load().
- Use Web Methods:

  ```
   [WebMethod]
   public static void StoreDetails(int uid)
   {
   }
  ```

  Call it in JavaScript:

  ```
  PageMethods.SetName(parameterValue, onSuccess, onFail);
  ```

  You need to initialize page methods:

  ```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptMgr" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
  ```
- Do it all client-side. Of course this depends on what you're doing with the posted data.